# Build Gradle в IntelliJ IDEA требует более новую версию java, но вроде она установлена

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я получаю ошибку >Found java version 1.8.0. Minimum required is 1.8.0_101, но у меня установлена 1.8.0_341 судя по названию папки. Как я могу это исправить?[image: Ошибка в IntelliJ IDEA]

[image: Папка с java]

UPD: Консоль вообще говорит о третьей версии... Конфиг java сообщает ту же, что и в названии папки[image: Консоль]

Comment: Путь до JDK указывается в настройках проекта для компиляции, версия JRE не является версией для разработки, она для запуска уже скомпилированных программ.

Comment: JDK стоит 19-ый. Если JRE это не java, тогда что требует от меня ошибка?

Comment: File->Project Settings и смотрите, какие настройки у вашего проекта. Так же версия может указываться в файлах настройки проекта, в вашем случае gradle как я понимаю.

Comment: Не понимаю, что я должен тут увидеть помимо того, что как я и сказал стоит 19 JDK. Возможно в gradle что-то не так, но файла properties у меня нету, а без него как я вычитал java ищется через команды. У меня есть несколько JDK, но они явно не 1.8.0. Поэтому я думаю это все таки версия JRE.